# arangodb server connection refused

Tags: browser, arangodb, connection-refused

I installed the newest version of ArangoDB on my Mac (macOS High Sierra) and when I try to connect to the server via

```
*localhost:~ davidoff$ arangosh --server.username "root" --server.database _SYSTEM*
```

I get the following error message:

> Could not connect to endpoint 'http+tcp://127.0.0.1:8529', database: '_SYSTEM', username: 'root'
>   Error message: 'Could not connect to 'http+tcp://127.0.0.1:8529' 'connect() failed with #61 - Connection refused'

I couldn't open `http://localhost:8529` via the browser either.
Same error message. Any recommendations how to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

Is _SYSTEM a database that exists? The default should be _system

Answer (score 2):

Double check `endpoint` value in `/etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf`

If necessary, update `/etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf`, or add `--server.endpoint tcp://YOURENDPOINTHOST:8529` to the command line parameters.

Run `/etc/init.d/arangodb3 start` or reboot (arangodb should start automatically).

Comment: Thanks, @KTCO! I solved the problem now with another method. I completely uninstalled arangodb, stopped all running arangod instances, deleted all related folders, reinstalled it and now can access it again.

Comment: @David it would be nice of you if you post your solution as an answer and further accept it once it's possible. This way you'll indicate that the issue was solved to those who find the question by SO search.